# Getting single row returned from SELECT statement with joined tables without Group By

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three tables. One with customer data, one with documents, and one with images.
If multiple documents exist in the documents or images tables, multiple rows are returned. I'm only needing one row returned. 
The table row in my application has links that directs them to the images and documents page for each Customer ID, so it's important that I include the document and image file name in my select statement. 
The problem is multiple rows are showing up for the same customer ID because multiple documents/images exist for each customer. Group By doesn't seem to help me as I still get multiple rows.

```
Customer ID | Title    | Documents Link | Images Link
----------------------------------------------------
Sam Tucker  | Salesman | Link           | Link
Sam Tucker  | Salesman | Link           | Link
Sam Tucker  | Salesman | Link           | Link

SELECT DISTINCT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.Title, Documents.FileName, Images.FileName
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Documents
ON Customer.CustomerID = Documents.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Images
ON Customer.CustomerID =  Images.CustomerID
```

Here is the reason I need the filename in my select statement. If the filename does not exist, the link will not be visible. Also, the link isn't an actual link to the file but a modal that displays multiple files.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Documents" runat="server" Text="Link" Click="MyMethod" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Documents.FileName").ToString()) ? false : true %>'></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="Images" runat="server" Text="Link" OnClick="MyMethod2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Images.FileName").ToString()) ? false : true %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

How can I return only one row?

Comment: If you want single row, which document or image you want to return if there are multiple?

Comment: @RohitShetty It doesn't matter. I've just edited my comments to mention that the link isn't an actual file but a modal that displays multiple files. So, it shouldn't matter what file is returned. If a file exists in the table a link will be displayed and if no files exist, no link will show. I just want one single row to be displayed in the table.

Comment: i have added an answer, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `MAX` to get the results you are looking for.

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.Title, MAX(Documents.FileName), 
MAX(Images.FileName)
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Documents ON Customer.CustomerID = Documents.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Images ON Customer.CustomerID =  Images.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID, Customer.Title
```

Comment: With aggregates, there is no reason to use distinct.